# How to check whether android EditText keyboard Auto Suggestion is enabled or not?

Tags: android, android-edittext, rich-text-editor

In my project I am working on EditText.I have set an input type for this EditText using below code.

```
mEdit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT 
                       | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES 
                       | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

If we disabled the Auto Suggestion using keyboard settings, How to know Autosuggestion is enabled or disabled While editing. I need to know this in onTextChanged listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this

```
 if(mEdit.getInputType() == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS){
}
```

But never tried.